# Why is the exterior paint of my truck not coming out matte rather than shiny after buffing it with a buffer

Tags: chevrolet, paint, paint-clearcoat, polishing

Why is my truck not coming out shiny after buffing it with a buffer Instead it looks door or like a matte finish

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please rectify you question versus your heading? They are sort of a mismatch. Also, please include what exactly you're doing to get to where you're going in your polishing regime. Might even post pictures of exactly what you're talking about to better describe.

Comment: Is it the paint of the whole vehicle that is not polishing as you expect, or just parts of the vehicle?

Comment: Are you using a car polish, a wax or some other liquid or paste car finish product with the buffer? Or are you just using a dry, clean buffer bonnet?